# Custom \Rightarrow and \Leftrightarrow

Tags: lengths, white-space

Is there any way to shorten the double equal horizontal lines so they do not cross the arrow tips?

Also, if I can get rid of the white space between two horizontal lines, it would be perfect.
[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,arrows}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{green}{A \raisebox {0.35ex} {\tikz{\draw [double equal sign distance, -{Straight Barb[round, angle=60:1.5pt 1]}] (0,0) --++ (0.3,0)}} B \qquad C \raisebox {0.35ex} {\tikz{\draw[implies-implies,double equal sign distance,{Straight Barb[round, angle=60:1.5pt 1]}-{Straight Barb[round, angle=60:1.5pt 1]}] (0,0) -- (0.4,0);}} D}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So you want the `\rightarrow`, etc., with the un-curved peak?

Comment: Yes. If it has the "Straight Barb" arrow tip, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you simply use:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

    \colorbox{green}{A $\Rightarrow$ B \qquad C $\Leftrightarrow$ D}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and with loading `XITS Math`

[image]

Running with `xelatex`. or `lualatex` on macOS

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

    \colorbox{green}{A $\Rightarrow$ B \qquad C $\Leftrightarrow$ D}

\end{document}
```

with the file list (at end of the log file)

```
*File List*
standalone.cls    2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
shellesc.sty    2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
libertinus.sty    2018/09/03 v. 0.01 (Herbert Voss) Supports libertinus fonts f
or pdflatex/lualatex/xelatex
libertinus-otf.sty    2018/11/18 v. 0.13 (Herbert Voss and Bob Tennent) Support
s libertinus fonts for lualatex and xelatex.
textcomp.sty    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
unicode-math.sty    2018/07/29 vv0.8m Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2018-11-19 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2018-11-19 L3 programming layer 
l3xdvipdfmx.def    
unicode-math-xetex.sty    2018/07/29 vv0.8m Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
  xparse.sty    2018-10-17 L3 Experimental document command parser
l3keys2e.sty    2018-10-17 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
fontspec.sty    2018/07/30 vv2.6h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2018/07/30 vv2.6h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
  fix-cm.sty    2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got this error:
fontspec error: "font-not-found"
The font "XITS Math" cannot be found.

Comment: try it with `\usepackage{libertinus}` instead of setting the math font. Run it also with `xelatex`

Comment: New error: File `libertinus.sty' not found.

Comment: Update your TeX-Distribution. Which one do you have?

Comment: I had 1.34. Now I updated to 1.35, but the error is the same. On Tex Live Utility the package libertinus shows "Installed".

Comment: what is 1.35?? If libertinus is installed then the package should be found ...

Comment: I'm using MacTex (now updating to 2018) and I have no idea why this error still appears since libertinus is already installed.
I think that if I can't use the libertinus package or XITS Math, I will have to draw that arrows with Tikz.

Comment: See my edited answer. There is  a file list when running xelatex on macOS

Comment: I have libertinus installed, but I just saw that libertinus-fonts is NOT installed. How can I install it?

Comment: there must be a package  `libertinus-fonts`

Comment: It worked after installing missing packages, but now my main font has changed.

Comment: What main font do you want? It is no problem to use libertines for math and for text anotherone

Comment: I'm using \setmainfont[Kerning=On,Mapping=tex-text]{Myriad Pro} and since my book has 2 languages (english and greek), I use also the packages fontspec, xgreek and polyglossia. Maybe one of these is the problem. Trying to solve my initial problem with the 2 languages, I ended up with these packages, so I don't know what to do with libertinus so it does not change my main font.

Comment: Put  your `\setmainfont{...}` _after_  `\usepackage{libertinus}`.  That's all.

Comment: Errors are endless! Now it says: Command \dddot already defined. I think it's the amsmath.sty. I don't know if it has any point, but I'm using \usepackage{amsthm} in my book.

Comment: Load amsmath _before_. Fontspec or Unicode-math

Comment: No difference by putting amsmath before fontspec. Same error: Command \dddot already defined.

Comment: Can you post your preamble?

Comment: It's quite big. May I send it to you in chat, or here in public?

Comment: herbert@dante.de